# Using play's wsclient to make a call to fetch a RSS feed and return a collection

Tags: scala, playframework

I am making a request to a URL to grab the RSS xml data:

```
 val items: List[Item] = ws.url("http://www.example.com/rss.xml").get().map { response =>

 }
```

Now I want to loop through all the  nodes and create a collection of Items.

My Item case class is:

```
 case class Item(title: String, link: String, description: String, guid: String)
```

The format of the XML is like below:

```
 <rss ...>
   <channel>
      <title>
      </title>
      <link />
      <description />
      <item>
        <title>hello</title>
        <description> ... </description>
        <guid> ... </guid>
      </item>
      <item>
      ...
      </item>
    </channel>
 </rss>
```

I'm not sure what to do with the response in the call to .map to iterate through the items and how to return a collection of Item case classes.

Comment: Did you check out the official documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#processing-a-response-as-xml. Here is another resource to be able to work with xml : http://alvinalexander.com/scala/xml-parsing-xpath-extract-xml-tag-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should basically use the xml api to extract the relevant `NodeSeq`, which works like any collection.
Then you map each node to extract the relevant subtag content and create an object out of it.

```
val itemNodes = response.xml \\ "item" //will get all item nodes as a NodeSeq
val item = itemNodes.map(node => 
        Item(
          (node \ "title").text,
          "", // there's no link tag in the item
          (node \ "description").text,
          (node \ "guid").text
        )
      )
```

If not exactly this, something similar